# How to change UIButton background color when its inside a UIStackView

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

I am trying to insert a pre-loaded UIStackView into another StackView.
In The pre-loaded UIStackView i have sub-views which i added programmatically.
The problem is that when i add buttons and set their color, they get white background, and no corner radius at all

I tried using "background = new UIColor(51,181,229,255)"
and "background = UIColor.FromCGColor(51,181,229,255)"

with same results..

```
        //TextFields
        UITextField oldPasswordTextField = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "Old Password",
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            ClipsToBounds = true
        };

        UITextField newPasswordTextField = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "New Password",
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            ClipsToBounds = true
        };

        UITextField repPasswordTextField = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "Repeat New Password",
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            ClipsToBounds = true
        };

        //Buttons
        UIButton cancelButton = new UIButton();           
        cancelButton.SetTitle("Cancel", UIControlState.Normal);
        cancelButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
        cancelButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromCGColor(new CoreGraphics.CGColor(51, 181, 229, 255));
        cancelButton.ClipsToBounds = true;

        UIButton submitButton = new UIButton();
        submitButton.SetTitle("Submit", UIControlState.Normal);
        submitButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
        //submitButton.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(51, 181, 229, 255);
        submitButton.ClipsToBounds = true;


        passwordChangeStackView.AddArrangedSubview(oldPasswordTextField);
        passwordChangeStackView.AddArrangedSubview(newPasswordTextField);
        passwordChangeStackView.AddArrangedSubview(repPasswordTextField);
        passwordChangeStackView.AddArrangedSubview(submitButton);
        passwordChangeStackView.AddArrangedSubview(cancelButton);
        passwordChangeStackView.AddArrangedSubview(activityIndicator);
```

MainStackView.InsertArrangedSubview(passwordChangeStackView, 2); //2 -> after related button

I need the buttons to be with my chosen color, with white text,
and all the subviews to have rounded corners... but i cant manage to get both to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **background = new UIColor(51,181,229,255)**, however your parameter in this function is **wrong**.

> An RGB color value is specified with: rgb(red, green, blue).
>
> Each parameter (red, green, and blue) defines the intensity of the
>   color as an integer between 0 and 255.
>
> For example, rgb(0, 0, 255) is rendered as **blue**, because the blue
>   parameter is set to its highest value (255) and the others are set to
>   0.

Let's take a look at the definition:

```
  //UIColor constructor from red, green, blue and alpha components.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   red:
        //     Red component, 0.0 to 1.0f.
        //
        //   green:
        //     Green component 0.0 to 1.0f.
        //
        //   blue:
        //     Blue component value 0.0 to 1.0f.
        //
        //   alpha:
        //     Alpha (transparency) value from 0.0 to 1.0f.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     This can be used from a background thread.
        [BindingImpl(BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
        [Export("initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:")]
        public UIColor(nfloat red, nfloat green, nfloat blue, nfloat alpha);
```

So in your case, you can use:

`submitButton.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(51/255.0f, 181/255.0f, 229/255.0f, 255/255.0f);`

Answer (score 0):

Had to use UIColor.FromRGBA ..... now its working